# Can not do 'DB Action' on my Oracle Autonomous DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I created my first Autonomous database "Always Free" on OCI. The provisioning have gone well and the db exists in my compartment.

However, when I click on "DB Action" to start adding tables I get the message @ Database Action: "Please wait initialising DB Action". Nothing more is happening and I cannot get further.

Anyone here that knows what the problem may be?

A friend of mine tested and succeeded and ended up in the admin console but not me.

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? If Chrome, try opening it with Developer Tools (cache disabled checked)

Comment: I am using Safari.

Comment: safari on a mobile device? can you try again on Chrome?

Comment: Well, I have not tried Crome yet but will do. BTW do you think it can have anything to do with that I am currently not in my registered home region?

Comment: by default on always free there aren't any networking rules to prevent access...so unless you went into your console and made changes, don't think so

Comment: As I am going home tomorrow I will test again at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari most likely [blocked the pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzKuH.png)
. Just click on the pop-up icon and the DB Actions should open.

Comment: This is what happen. I changed webb browser to FireFox.